# Fetch data in descending order by default (without orderby) from partitioned table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to learn partitioning a single table in SQL Server and implemented the example given in https://www.sqlshack.com/database-table-partitioning-sql-server/.

**Question:** my partition on a table named `Reports` is based on column named `ReportDate`.

When I retrieve the records from a partitioned table they are always sorted in ascending (by default) order by `ReportDate` even though I created the clustered index on `ReportDate` in descending order.

```
Select top 10 * 
from Reports
```

This query returns records like this:

```
2020-01-01
2020-02-01
.
.
.
```

Expected result:

```
2020-12-31
2020-11-30
.
.
.
```

My default use case is to fetch the latest records first, can we do it in partitioned table? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "default" order when `ORDER BY` is omitted. Order is "undefined" so SQL Server may return rows in any order it chooses. This undefined order can differ due to factors like indexing, isolation level, parallelism, and partitioning. Furthermore, the order may differ by SQL Server version, edition, patch level, and which way the wind is blowing. [`ORDER BY` is required](https://www.dbdelta.com/order-by-is-required/) if you need results returned in a particular order.

That being said, the actual execution plan of the trivial `SELECT * FROM Reports` query reveals insight into why the undefined order differs with and without table partitioning. Both plans show the first (and only in the case of non-partitioned table) partition is accessed and rows are returned with a scan of the clustered index in key order (`ReportDate` descending) due to the `READ_COMMITTTED` isolation level.

```
<RunTimePartitionSummary>
  <PartitionsAccessed PartitionCount="1">
    <PartitionRange Start="1" End="1" />
  </PartitionsAccessed>
</RunTimePartitionSummary>
<IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
  <DefinedValues>
    <DefinedValue>
      <ColumnReference Database="[tempdb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Reports]" Column="ReportDate" />
    </DefinedValue>
  </DefinedValues>
  <Object Database="[tempdb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Reports]" Index="[cdx]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
</IndexScan>
```

Note, however, the first partition of the partitioned table contains only rows less than or equal to the first partition boundary (with `RANGE LEFT` partition function). The "undefined" order of the partitioned table query is the partition function boundary month ascending followed by `ReportDate` descending (clustered index key sequence within each partition).

An important side note is that indexing strategies differ with and without partitioning. The partition number is conceptually similar to the leftmost index key. The partitioned table plan with the needed `ORDER BY ReportDate DESC` clause and descending index key does not leverage the descending index order in this case like one might expect, instead introducing a sort operator (with SQL 2019 CU6):

[image: descending index plan]

Since SQL Server can traverse b-tree indexes both forward and backward, it's not necessary to create descending indexes with a single key. The plan with the ascending index uses a more efficient backwards scan to provide the ordering:

[image: plan with ascending index]

Answer (score 2):

You can not rely on that! If you do not specify an `order by` clause then you have no guaranteed result order. So just add that to your query anyway.

```
select top 10 * from Reports order by ReportDate desc
```

Comment: Understood, Just curious why records are not coming in descending order even after putting cluster index in descending order like un-partitioned table.

Comment: They are not "coming in order". The order is undefined and will be determined by runtime conditions, the execution plan, the pages in memory, the pages that need to be brought into memory, the amount of available memory, etc. If you need order in a resultset, the only way to guarantee that is with an order by clause. Much like the use of "top 10" will return 10 rows of no and in no particular order.